# How to avoid hardcoding a control's name in a data verification rule function

Tags: vba, ms-access

Goal: Avoid hard coding the control's name in my VBA data verification function

I have a control which has a data validation rule.

It calls a user defined function that measures how many decimals have been entered in the control.

```
Function GetDPstr() As Integer
    ' Returns for the number of decimal places in a string
    
    Dim NumberBox   As Control
    'Error here: I would like to be able to implicitly access the control's value without
    'having to hard code the control's name so I can reuse the code for other controls
    'as opposed to using "Me.Controls!ControlName"
    Set NumberBox = Me.txtbox


    
    If Len(NumberBox) - Len(Replace(NumberBox, ".", "")) = 0 Then        ' test for decimal point separator
    GetDPstr = 0
Else
    GetDPstr = Len(RTrim(NumberBox)) - InStr(RTrim(NumberBox), ".")
End If
End Function
```

Comment: Get the Control as a paramenter in your UDF and call it by control. IE: `Function GetDecimals(NumberBox As Control) As Integer`

Comment: But _dot_ is not always the decimal separator, so ...